# jQuery ajax POST returning results in blank page

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, python-2.7, bottle

**Expected Behaviour**

01 - Form is posted using jQuery.
02 - Authorisation is processed.
03 - MongoDB query is performed.
04 - Results should be returned in place of form.

**Actual Behaviour**

Steps 1 - 3 complete, however step 4 doesn't; the correct results are being returned but in a blank page.

**Form**

```
<form name="login" id="login">
<p>username</p>
<p>password</p>
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" />
<button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#login').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/login',
data: $(this).serialize(),
dataType: 'json',
success: function(results) {
$("#content_area").html("");
$("#content_area").append(results.content);
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

**Python**

```
@post('/login')
def login():
    """Authenticate users"""
    username = post_get('username')
    password = post_get('password')
    aaa.login(username, password, fail_redirect='/login')
    dbname = 'mydb'
    connection = pymongo.MongoClient(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL'])
    db = connection[dbname]
    collection = db.myCollection
    href = 'my-title'
    query = {'title':href}
    projection = {'_id':0,'content':1}
    cursor = collection.find_one(query,projection)
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    return dumps(cursor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

The contents of the login form page (ie the `<form>` not the html `<head>`) was loaded by getJSON().

Long story short, I thought:

> What if the jQuery isn't loading properly because the content was
>   loaded via getJSON()?

So I changed the jQuery script to use `.on` ie:

```
<script>
$(document).on("submit","#login", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/login',
data: $(this).serialize(),
dataType: 'json',
success: function(results) {
$("#content_area").html("");
$("#content_area").append(results.content);
}
});
});
</script>
```

And now it loads correctly in the specified div.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
response.content_type = 'application/json'
```

with this:

```
response.set_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
```

(Just a guess.)

Comment: For reference, that did not have an effect.

Comment: Oops, just realized: it should be `content-type`, not `content_type`.  I'll correct my answer--and with a little luck that will solve your problem.

Comment: That did not have an effect.

Comment: Bummer.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears when you have a `document.write()` call during the ajax request.